# Using "lay-by" as verb for buying goods

Tags: vocabulary, colloquial-language

> **lay by**, 1 : to lay aside : discard, 2 : to store for future use : save, 3 : to cultivate (as corn) for the last time (Merriam Webster)

Considering that Merriam Webster's definition of "lay-by" as a verb is the above, can we say, for example, "I'll *lay-by* it for Christmas"?

I'm asking because it is not difficult to find "lay-by" used in reference to buy goods, albeit there are no referenced sites that I can show; rather it seems a colloquialism.

Comment: "I'll lay-by it for Christmas" would be incorrect. It would be "I'll lay it by for Christmas" or "I'll put it aside for Christmas."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some retailers may have what's called a "[layaway](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/layaway)" plan for people who want to buy something  before they have enough cash to pay for it. When I was a kid, this was very popular. That was before credit cards and easy credit. In Taiwan, most retailers will sell you an item and give it to you if you sign a contract to pay it off in 3 or 6 or 12 months. Nobody wants to wait for things these days.

The Macmillan Dictionary (British English edition) says that *[lay-by](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lay-by_1)* is the Australian term for the American term *layaway*.

Comment: +1 Googling 'lay by sales' yields many hits which reveal, *inter alia*, that **1)** in Australia and New Zealand it is a legal term, not a colloquialism, and **2)** it is in fact the equivalent of US *layaway*: the seller holds on to the goods sold until payment is complete.

Comment: UK usage would be *lay by*, but I don't think that the expression is now in common usage. You could also say *put by*.